# Ajax Call Sometimes Fails and Sometimes Works?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an application which outputs a table via ajax, each row of the table has a column / input field for schedule date. once the schedule date has been entered the update button within that row is clicked and my second ajax call is fired.

Problem I am having, when selecting the date and click the update button sometimes the system works and sometimes it doesn't.. see my code - I hope somebody can shed some light.

**First Ajax Call:**

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
                todayHighlight:'TRUE',
                autoclose: true,
            })

    $.post('assets/ajax/calldata/newords.php', function(data) {
        $('#newords').html(data)
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                todayHighlight:'TRUE',
                autoclose: true,
            })
    });
```

**Output from first Ajax Call**

```
<table>

  <thead>
  <tr>
    <td>#<td>
    <td>Account</td>
    <td>Date to Scedule</td>
    <td>Action</td>
  <tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Test Account</td>
      <td>
          <input class="datepicker form-control" type="text" id="datetoprint" name="datepicker" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
      </td>
      <td>
          <button class="btn btn-default markScheduled" type="button" id="markScheduled" ordid="56">Scheduled</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Second Ajax Call after clicking update on row:**

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.markScheduled', function(e) {

        var ordid = $(this).attr('ordid');
        var scheduledate = $('input.scheduleDate').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "assets/ajax/order.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {ordid: ordid,date: scheduledate},
            success: function(result){

            },
            error: function(exception){
                alert('Exception:' +exception);
            }
        });

        $.post('assets/ajax/calldata/newords.php', function(data) {
            $('#newords').html(data)
            $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                todayHighlight:'TRUE',
                autoclose: true,
            })
        });

    });
```

I get no error, this system refreshes updates the database sometimes takes the value from the input and sometimes not.. sometimes you have to manually refresh the page for the entry to no longer be on screen..

Comment: And when it fails, do you have any error??? But it sounds like you should call second ajax request **only** once first one completed/succeded

Comment: see in console when it is failing ....try putting the $.post inside your $.ajax success and see.

Comment: I get no error, this system refreshes updates the database sometimes takes the value from the input and sometimes not.. sometimes you have to manually refresh the page for the entry to no longer be on screen..

Comment: Why are you initialising datepicker 3times?  No need for that..

Comment: @areim OP is updating `#newords` content which i guess contains `.datepicker` element(s). So in this case, this would make sense because AFAIK, datepicker plugin doesn't support any kind of delegation

Answer (score 0):

Missing some context in your question to make it clearer but sounds like you should call `post` request only once former request as succeded, e.g:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.markScheduled', function (e) {

    var ordid = $(this).attr('ordid');
    var scheduledate = $('input.scheduleDate').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "assets/ajax/order.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            ordid: ordid,
            date: scheduledate
        },
        error: function (exception) {
            alert('Exception:' + exception);
        }
    }).done(function () {
        $.post('assets/ajax/calldata/newords.php', function (data) {
            $('#newords').html(data).find('.datepicker').datepicker({
                todayHighlight: 'TRUE',
                autoclose: true
            });
        });
    });
});
```

That's said, you'd have better to use only one request to update database and handling returned result on page...

Comment: How do I output to chrome console?